# So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish

Tags: discussion

Well...  There is a time to come and a time to go and the time to go has come.  **;-)**

So I've landed a new job and my time is being taken up for more then 100% (>8 hours/day) during the first week on the job and will keep on going to be taken up for that amount of time in the foreseeable future, so it's better to leave an off-topic question as a farewell then to keep dropping into chat and say good bye to everyone individually or leaving comments below their answers over the next couple of days so:

1. Yes, I'm keeping my account
2. Nope, it doesn't look like I'll be doing any queue reviewing soon
3. Nope, it doesn't look like I'm going to drop into chat soon.
4. Yeah, I might be back in a couple of months...

For those who have my Tox ID, email address, phone number and/or credit card number: good for you, keep it, contact me whenever you want, but *please don't share it with anyone else without contacting me first!*

[So Long, and Thanks for All the Fish!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Long,_and_Thanks_for_All_the_Fish)

Comment: I wish you all the very, very best and good luck for this new site in your book of life Fabby, my dear friend ! :)

Comment: tsk. it's pretty easy to juggle both a job and AU.

Comment: My guess is: you can live without us at least 2, 3 days :)

Comment: ...But seriously, het ga je goed, en tot ziens!

Comment: You definitely make this community a lively one..Hope we'll see you soon.. All the very best.

Comment: Fabby you will definitely be missed, I don't really know how to thank you for all you've done for the community, and even me specifically. I hope to see you sometime soon!

Comment: All the best Fabby, we had some fun together. Veel plezier!

Comment: All the very best luck in your new endeavor. We will miss seeing you but, hopefully, not for long!

Comment: Ah! **[42](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/42)** upvotes!

Comment: Wish I had your credit card number ;) . Anyway, Good luck with your new job

Comment: *[than](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Than-and-Then)* it is.

Comment: @Fabby The meaning of life, the universe, and everything :D

Comment: @Fabby you will be missed. I wish you continued success in all your endeavors!

Comment: up voted only because of the funny title :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Officially:** thanks for all the time you've invested here and all the best in your new job.

**Unofficially:** *noooooooo...* You will definitely be missed.

Answer (score 16):

I am sad to hear that you will be leaving our community, for me, and I think many of us you have been a very integral part of the community, helping new users, having a great sense of humour, always willing to lend a hand and your great Q&As as well as many other things of course! **;-)** We will all miss you very much!

Though I am very pleased to hear that you have found a new job and wish you all the best in that and life. I do hope however that you will, even if rarely, pop into the chat room just to say hello! **:-)**

By the way, you're welcome for all the fish! **;P**

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for everything you did, not only for the site but also for the community. You introduced many of us and helped us getting started here, me included.

We'll surely miss you in the chat, but go on and excel in your new job!

Answer (score 14):

Special events sometimes force special actions ... so here it is : my first post on Ask Ubuntu Meta !

Even though it is not the most amazing "question" to answer, I wanna take the opportunity to say THANKS - THANKS for everything ! It is absolutely impossible to list all the positive contributions that you have provided our community with, your spirit will always be present in the background.

Once you said to me : "We old farts have to stick together !" I will never forget this sentence and now I say to you : "Dear old fart, stay young at heart !" - which means - just stay the way you are !

Now to answer your "question" : [You say Goodbye and I say Hello](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rblYSKz_VnI)  - Hello to the AU Hall of Fame ! Welcome there and also welcome back on the *"normal AU platform"* ... when ever this will be ... **:)**

Comment: :D :D :D :D :D :D

Answer (score 6):

Too bad a fellow Dutch speaker (judging by the answer of Jacob Vlijm) is leaving. At least for the time being... I hope you'll enjoy your new job and have a good time.

Answer (score 3):

here a late one from me.

Thanks for your time here? Sure. For your contribution? Absolutely.

Most of all however I want to say thank you for your being supportive, your good intentions and involvement in everything you do, and for being human. You're one of a kind. They'll have a good one in you.

Again, het ga je goed en kom nog eens langs!

Answer (score 2):

May you be happy in your job
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Heh, if i am late I am stupid.

Well good luck on your job :) Youve helped me when I was small, i couldn't thank you enough. Now go get em!

(WE HAVE REACHED TOP META POST! time for celebrations)

Answer (score 0):

Less FAT, more fish !? 8oþ

Less ext4, ext3 and ext2 then more fish too !? 8o|

Less vFAT, is less FAT is more fish ! :::o(

;o/

(sniff)

Comment: Whatever you want to tell us that way...